# Remove all labels for Neo4j Node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following examples are taken from the Neo4j documentation found [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-remove.html).

Using Cypher, it is possible to remove a single, known label using a Cypher statement like so:

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
REMOVE n:German
RETURN n
```

You can also remove multiple labels like so:

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
REMOVE n:German:Swedish
RETURN n
```

So how would one remove all labels from a node using simple Cypher statements?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this way using `doIt` method from `apoc` library:

```
match (n {name: 'Peter'})
call apoc.cypher.doIt(
  "match (o)" +
  " where ID(o) = " + ID(n) +
  " remove "+reduce(a="o",b in labels(n) | a+":"+b) + 
  " return (o);",
null)
yield value
return value
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntax for that yet! Labels are usually things that are known quantities, so you can list them all out if you want. There's no dynamic way to remove them all, though.

Comment: This is a big problem.  There's no way to remove all labels and there doesn't appear to be a way to update a node so that it includes only the specific labels you want. In other words, if a Node has labels l1 and l2, and I want to update it have labels l1 and l3, there doesn't appear to be a way to SET the labels to l1 and l3 without explicitly removing l2.  We use labels to represent types. If the type of the Node changes in our application, we want to be able to update the labels on the node to reflect that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you know all the labels in your graph, which you should, you can just do something like `match (n) remove n:label1:label2:label3:labelN` -- it's ugly but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

so, how about a two step cypher approach? use cypher to generate some cypher statements and then execute your cypher statements in the shell.

You could try something like this to generate the batch cypher statements

```
match (n) 
return distinct "match (n" 
+ reduce( lbl_str= "", l in labels(n) | lbl_str + ":" + l) 
+ ") remove n" 
+ reduce( lbl_str= "", l in labels(n) | lbl_str + ":" + l) 
+ ";"
```

The output should look something like this...

```
match (n:Label_1:Label_2) remove n:Label_1:Label_2;
match (n:Label_1:Label_3) remove n:Label_1:Label_3;
match (n:Label_2:Label_4) remove n:Label_2:Label_4;
```

You would probably want to remove any duplicates and depending on your data there could be quite a few.

Not exactly what you are looking for but I think it would get you to the same end state using just cypher and the neo4j shell.

---

**Shiny NEW and improved cypher below...**

I edited this down to something that would work in the browser alone.  It hink this is a much better solution. It is still two steps but it produces a single statement that can be cut and paste into the browser.

```
match (n) 
with distinct labels(n) as Labels
with reduce(lbl_str="", l in Labels | lbl_str + ":" + l) as Labels
order by Labels
with collect(Labels) as Labels
with Labels, range(0,length(Labels) - 1) as idx
unwind idx as i
return "match (n" + toString(i) + Labels[i] + ")" as Statement
union
match (n) 
with distinct labels(n) as Labels
with reduce(lbl_str="", l in Labels | lbl_str + ":" + l) as Labels
order by Labels
with collect(Labels) as Labels
with Labels, range(0,length(Labels) - 1) as idx
unwind idx as i
return "remove n" + toString(i) + Labels[i] as Statement
```

which produces output like this...

```
match (n0:Label_A)
match (n1:Label_B)
match (n2:Label_C:Label_D)
match (n3:Label_E)
remove n0:Label_A
remove n1:Label_B
remove n2:Label_C:Label_D
remove n3:Label_E
```

which can then be cut and paste into the Neo4j browser.

Comment: could add a `distinct` to the cyher so you don't need to sort out the dupes after :)

Comment: I think the OP was asking for how this could be done using just Cypher itself. Once you have to use the Neo4j shell, you could do just about anything manually.

Comment: yes, i agree they wanted a single statement; it is still cypher though. I think what you mean is something that could be run in the browser only?  Either way, it made me think a little about a browser only solution that would still be two steps but could be run in the browser.  So i crafted the addition above.